SQL : splitting of column value
I have a table with a column Decision which contains multiple values separated by comma (,). The values should be split into separate values and create multiple rows.
Please see the screenshot where I have highlighted the value that needs to be split in yellow box.
The desired result should be like:
Product+availability alone should populate in one row, copying rest of the row values and pricing should populate in another row, copying rest of the row values.
Give me SQL query

There's no image and you shouldn't upload images, but provide both sample input data and expected result as tables with text.

Does this answer your question? Split Comma separated Strings into Rows using Bigquery

Hi @yugesh R, Could you check this similar stack link ? Let me know if this helped you or not.

@DhirajSingh The question you have mentioned is about MySQL, not Google-Bigquery. I already linked a  matching duplicate question, see my comment above yours.
